# QT failed to deploy application code 0xc000007b

Tags: c++, qt

recently i have started to learn qt using c++;
I want to build an app to run on window, it ran fine when using QtCreator. but when i go to release folder and open .exe file, it showed that i missing **qt6core.dll, qt6widgets.dll , qt6gui.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll.**

So i google about then use windeployqt to deploy it, windeploy added missing files and i open .exe again then there is still error **0xc000007b**.

after that i used dependcy walker to check missing dll and there alot like this:

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyC9s.png)  [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVbzG.png)

Comment: Both of your pictures are known false positives when using depends. Use this tool instead of depends to avoid false positives with modern windows: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help for me. I was missing libstdc++-6.dll .